# getStaticProps not working when fetching the Laravel API and throw Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000

Tags: php, laravel, api, next.js

#### I have two main folder the `backend` laravel api and the `frontend` for next.js

[image]

#### I've configured axios file inside my `/lib/axios.ts`

[image]

#### I also created `fetcher` file in which you don't need to specify the absolute url path of your backend because it's already been configured in axios

[image]

#### My connection between my next.js app and laravel API works perfectly fine but when I tried to used `getStaticProps` inside my `dashboard.tsx` page file and use fetcher I got this error

[image]

#### This is my code.

#### What I liked to do is to make a pre-fill data in which the initial page load should have a default data in my dashboard page but it turns out an error and I used `swr` by the way.

[image]

#### When I tried to fetched it in another dummy API it works fine.

[image]

#### Do you think there will be an issue between serverside laravel api when fetching to and Static Site Generation in Next.js? Let me know what you know.

Answer (score 1):

With getServerSideProps or getStaticProps you need to have absolute URL's.

You currently have

```
...('/api/dashboards') //This is not an absolute url
```

What you need is something like this

```
...('http://localhost:8000/api/dashboards') //or whatever port it is on.
```

Keep in mind when you push to staging or something like that the url will no longer be `localhost` so you would be best to use a env file.

Final product would end up looking like this

```
...('${process.env.CURRENT_URL}/api/dashboards')
```

.env.development

```
CURRENT_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

.env.production

```
CURRENT_URL=https://example.com
```

Simple fetch

```
const response = await fetch('${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/dashboards')
const res = await response.json()
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried it too. Here 
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const prefechedData = await fetcher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/dashboards`) // https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

  return {
    props: {
      prefechedData
    }
  }
}

Comment: @JoshuaGalit Try the simple fetch at the bottom of my answer and let me know what is console logs.